# Структурная разновидность слогов

Tags: фонетика

Укажите структурную разновидность слогов в словах:

Сон, шелк, центр, взблеск, шторм, вдруг, взгляд, Омск

Comment: @Нармин Малиновская, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Comment: @Нармин Малиновская, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Открытым называется слог, оканчивающийся слогообразующим звуком: ва-та.

Закрытым называется слог, оканчивающийся неслоговым звуком: там, лай.

Неприкрытым называется слог, начинающийся на гласный звук: а-орта.

Прикрытым называется слог, начинающийся на согласный звук: ба-тон.

Омск- неприкрытый, закрытый;Остальные прикрытые,закрытые.